# Page redirection in JavaScript using a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect a page in JavaScript using a variable `base_url`. The issue is page redirects to the wrong URL rather than the one I want to redirect to.

The script is running on this page `http://www.example.com/account`

In my JS code, I have:

```
base_url = 'www.example.com';

window.location.href = base_url + '/payment';
```

How can I figure out how to send users to `www.example.com/payment` rather than `http://www.example.com/www.example.com/payment`?

I don't understand why my code is pre-pending the domain name in the URL? How can I solve this issue? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

OK guys, I changed my base url with

```
base_url = '//www.domainhole.com';
```

I am not sure whether the page will serve on http or https therefore I used protocol-relative URL.

But why without using `scheme` it makes wrong url?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `base_url = 'http://www.example.com';`?

Comment: Try using this window.location.replace = base_url + '/payment';

Comment: no, it loses history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a protocol in your base_url: `base_url = 'https://www.example.com';`